# Iterate over deque in python

Tags: python

Since a deque is a doubly linked list, I should be able to iterate through it in order without any performance cost compared to a list. However, the following will be *much* slower than iterating through a list

```
for i in range(0, len(d)):
    doSomethingWith(d[i])
```

Since each time it goes to `d[i]` starting at `d[0]`. How do I make it iterate properly?

Comment: [`deque`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) provided its own iterator, use it.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can directly iterate over the deque.

```
for i in d:
    doSomethingWith(i)
```

(see the examples in the documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque)

Answer (score 10):

I used a `while` loop for `deque` iteration, as follows:

```
from collections import deque

lst = [1,2,4,8]
queue=deque(lst)

print(queue)

while queue:
    print('{}{}'.format("head: ",queue[0]))
    queue.popleft()
```

**output:**

```
deque([1, 2, 4, 8])
head: 1
head: 2
head: 4
head: 8
```

Comment: This answer is very useful in case, you want to delete my iterating the queue.

Comment: Indeed, this is useful if you want to use the dequeue as an actual FIFO queue until empty